# Why does Django make unnecessary SQL queries in Change List View Page?

Tags: mysql, django, python-2.7, django-admin

I have a Django model say ,

```
class Student(models.Model):
    prefix           = models.CharField(max_length = 10, blank = True, null = True,)
    suffix           = models.CharField(max_length = 10, blank = True, null = True,)
    fullname         = models.CharField(max_length = 100, null = False,)
    fname            = models.CharField(max_length = 100, verbose_name = u'First Name', blank = True, null = True,)
    midname          = models.CharField(max_length = 100, verbose_name = u'Middle Name', blank = True, null = True,)
    lname            = models.CharField(max_length = 50, verbose_name = u'Last Name', default = ' ')
    department       = models.ForeignKey('Department')
```

In List Display (admin.py)

```
    list_display = ('fname', 'midname', 'lname', 'prefix', 'suffix',)
```

For this,  a simple select Query including the above fields is enough, But Django makes SQL queries in a complicated manner using inner joins when there is a FK. For example,

Normally django must implement

```
     SELECT 'fname', 'midname', 'lname', 'prefix', 'suffix' FROM student LIMIT 0,100;
```

But Django does the SELECT query for all the possible fields.

```
SELECT student.prefix.student.suffix .... deparment.id ,depatment.name ..... 
INNER JOIN department ON deparment.id = student.id ........ LIMIT 100
```

Can somebody give a reasonable  explanation as to why unnecessary queries are required ?

Comment: Because of simplicity and ubiquity I think? You may easily achieve it by overriding `ModelAdmin.queryset` manually or through some wrapping code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django won't foresee what fields the developer is going to choose . So it gives out all the fields to the admin templates inculding the fields from all the related tables . The developer  can override the admin templates if he requires to. 
  The queryset() will provide the ability to send custom sql statements.

Hope the question is answered.

Comment: But i feel it not an efficient way Django does

Answer (score 0):

Ho My Bad ! 
i was using list_filter = ['department__name']

So that it is INNER JOIN WITH department. I removed it now and its showing me the optimized Query

DJANGO ROCKS